# How to write the realisation of a composite function $(f\circ g):A\times B\to\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Let $A$ and $B$ be arbitrary sets with arbitrary elements $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. Further, let $f:A\times B\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g:A\times B\to B$ be functions. Then, consider the composition $f\circ g:A\times B\to\mathbb{R}$.

My question is simple: should I write the realisation of $(f\circ g)$ for any particular pair $(a,b)\in A\times B$ as $(f\circ g)(a,b)=f(g(a,b))$ or $(f\circ g)(a,b)=f(a,g(a,b))$?

Comment: See [Composition of multivariate functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition#Multivariate_functions)

Comment: $f$ requires an element of $A \times B$ as input.  $g(a,b) \in B \neq A \times B$, so "$f(g(a,b))$" is nonsense.

Comment: It is as Eric Towers said. $f\circ{g}$ is only defined whenever $f:Y\rightarrow{Z}$ and $g:X\rightarrow{Y}.$ That is how functional composition works. Your example does not satisfy that template, so what you have is not a valid composition of functions. Strictly speaking, composition of functions is itself a function $\circ:Z^Y\times{Y^X}\rightarrow{Z^X}.$